# Turn relay on from Bluetooth for certain amount of seconds

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working on two way communication between arduino and android phone. Currently everything is working, however I have couple of issues I have been trying to solve recently.

1. How I can ignite ignition for 5 seconds? I mean if IgnitionPin is on HIGH, run it for 5 seconds then automatically turn off? There is an easy way with delay, but it will not work in my case as don't want any other delays to slow up my script.
2. I am using Arduino Uno. I want to start my Arduino with pin in OFF position. Why pin 10 always turns ON then shuts down, even with  digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH); I have tried other pins and they work fine -> turned OFF on start.

```
SoftwareSerial BTserial(12,13);

char choice;

const int loopDelay = 50;

int IgnitionPin = 10;
const long ignitionInterval = 5000;
int ignitionState = HIGH;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

void setup() 
{
  BTserial.begin(115200);  

  digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(IgnitionPin, OUTPUT);
}
 
void loop()
{
  if (BTserial.available())
  {
    choice = BTserial.read();
  }

  if( choice == 'm' )
  {
    ignitionState = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, ignitionState);
    ignitionCountTime = millis();
  }

  if (ignitionCountTime - previousMillis >= ignitionInterval) {

    previousMillis = ignitionCountTime;

    if (ignitionState == HIGH) 
    {
      ignitionState = LOW;
    }

    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, ignitionState);
  }
 
 delay(loopDelay);
}
```

---

EDIT:

```
SoftwareSerial BTserial(12,13);

char choice;

const int loopDelay = 50;

int IgnitionPin = 10;
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long ignitionInterval = 30000;
unsigned long ignitionCountTime = 0;

void setup() 
{
  BTserial.begin(115200);  

  digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH);
  pinMode(IgnitionPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (BTserial.available())
  {
    choice = BTserial.read();
  }

  if( choice == 'm' )
  {
    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH);
    ignitionCountTime = millis();
  }

  if (ignitionCountTime - startTime >= ignitionInterval)
  {
    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, LOW);
  }

 delay(loopDelay);
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `choice`? You are setting `IgnitionPin` to `HIGH` in `setup`, shouldn't that be `LOW` and after the call to `pinMode`?

Comment: Q1- better solution is not use SoftwareSerial. HW UART is reliable then sw.
Q2- use millis() for measure time in not blocking way. Please see example Blink without Delay

Comment: @PeterPlesník ou, thank you very much for suggestion with HW over SS. I didn't know that. Just read all night yesterday about differences and now I understand how Arduino works a bit better! I have tried to go with millis() but don't fully get it working yet...

Comment: I have cleaned my code a bit and added my attempt with millis() that just blinks constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1
Use the TimerOne library or setup an ISR.
Run the ISR at, 5 times per second.

```
uint32_t timeout = 5 * 60;
uint8_t flag = 1;
digitalWrite (myPin, HIGH);

if (timeout && flag) {
    timeout--;
} else {
    digitalWrite (myPin, LOW);
    flag = 0;
}
```

OR
by checking time elapsed since some specific point in time.

```
unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long interval = 60000;
const byte aPin = 13;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(aPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(aPin, HIGH);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (millis() - startTime >= interval)
  {
    digitalWrite(aPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

EDIT

Arduino is a microcontroller, it can do only one thing at once.

```
SoftwareSerial BTserial(12,13);

char choice;

const int loopDelay = 50;

int IgnitionPin = 10;
uint32_t timeout = 5 * 60;
uint8_t flag = 0;

void setup() 
{
  BTserial.begin(115200);  

  pinMode(IgnitionPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  if (BTserial.available())
  {
    choice = BTserial.read();
  }

  if (choice == "m") 
   { 
    timeout = 5 * 60;  //modify this timeout.
    flag = 1;
    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH); 
   } 
   else if ((timeout > 0) && (flag == 1))
    {
            timeout--;
    }
   else 
    { 
       digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, LOW);
       flag = 0;
    }
   
 delay(loopDelay);
}
```

#2 - In setup you are running 'digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, HIGH);' this will make it high
just use pinMode(IgnitionPin, OUTPUT); for setting pin as output pin

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");

  BTserial.begin(115200);  

  sensors.begin(); 

  // Set Pin as an output pin
    pinMode(IgnitionPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, LOW);
}
```

If you want IgnitionPin as LOW at each restart - use 'digitalWrite(IgnitionPin, LOW);' in setup() after pinMode call.

Comment: Thank you for solutions! I have updated my code with your proposal. Now it seems to work better. However now after sending command "m" relay is ON for amount of time specified, but then after sending another "m" command nothing happens. How to make it work so that after sending command "m" relay would stay ON for 5 seconds and then go OFF. Then after sending "m" again it would perform the same action?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.